# Qt Creator and HIKVISON SDK

Tags: c++, sdk, qt-creator, hikvision

I am a beginner with Qt Creator I need to ask if I can USE HIKVISON SDK which downloaded from :
https://www.hikvision.com/en/support/download/sdk/device-network-sdk--for-windows-64-bit-/

can I import them to qt if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

I but file with lib name in same folder Qt project and add this two lines to .pro

LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ -lHCCore -lHCNetSDK -lPlayCtrl

LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/HCNetSDKCom -lHCAlarm -lHCGeneralCfgMgr -lHCPreview

include the header file and start to use the functions